# Nircmd: Invoking monitor using 'enter' key goes back again to monitor off state

Tags: nircmd

I have created a shortcut with below command  to turn-off laptop monitor (referred from this web [link](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/create-a-shortcut-or-hotkey-to-turn-off-the-monitor/)).

```
“C:\path\to\nircmd.exe” cmdwait 1000 monitor off
```

This solution is working fine for turning off the monitor. Since I double-click on the shortcut icon to turn-off monitor, icon is still in the selection after turn-off.

Due to this, when I use enter key to invoke monitor, it is turning on and again went into turn-off state because of enter key usage (enter executes the shortcut icon).

Though this behavior is obvious, it took a while to understand when it happened for the first time.

Is there any other option in nircmd to use the enter key for invoking monitor?

Comment: Honestly, my suggestion would be to get the habit if using another key to wake your computer (in general).  Preferably a non-destructive key, such as ctrl or alt.  Prevents things like this from happening. ;)

Answer (score 1):

The only thing I can think off is adding the code towards a shortcut and use an other shortcut key like ctrl + alt + F12 this way it wont be on the selection screen, else there no other method other than unbinding your enter key to execute a program.

**Edit:**

It is actually stated in the article probably for a reason.